# how to get text from element children?

Tags: javascript, string, text

I have a div element with some span children. I want to get the text of all spans with space between them and compare that text with a string. my code is here:

```js
var text = "this is some text in div";
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var divtext = "";
  for (i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
    divtext += div.children[i].innerHTML + " ";
  }
  console.log(divtext.localeCompare(text))
})
```

```html
<div id="div"><span>this</span><span>is</span><span>some</span><span>text</span><span>in</span><span>div</span></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

when I use `localeCompare` for string and div inner text the result should be 0 but it is not. where is the problem?

Comment: var text is missing that space you add to each div.children. make it `var text = "this is some text in div ";`and it wll match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison isn't equal (`0`), because there is a trailing space at the end of `divtext`.

If you assign the text from each `<span>` to an array, you can use the `Array.prototype.join` method to concatenate the values with a `' '` separator, thus eliminating the trailing space.

```js
var text = "this is some text in div";
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var divtext = [];
  for (i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
    divtext.push(div.children[i].innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(text.localeCompare(divtext.join(' ')));
})
```

```html
<div id="div"><span>this</span><span>is</span><span>some</span><span>text</span><span>in</span><span>div</span></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```